# Converting margin from pixel to percentage - breaks float left element

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I have the following HTML block:

```
  <div class="container clearfix">
  <div class="grid_8 omega">
     <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cupcakes &amp; Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Which is styled this way:

```
ul.nav {
  margin-top: 18.18%;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}

ul.nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

And this gives me the following result (Web developer toolbar outlines on):

[image: Screenshot1]

Now I am trying to change the 40px margin to percentage in order to make the site more fluid and from I have learnt I should use the target / context = result which in this case is 40px / 660px = 0.06 which is roughly 6%. I then change the 40px to 6% and I get the following instead:

[image: Screenshot2]

What have I done wrong here? The width of the ul block has shrunk and the margin-right is not changing when I resize the browser window. It seems no matter what amount of percentage I put in there is no value in percentage that makes this work at all. I must be using percentages wrong? Why isn't it working?

Comment: please post your related code so that we can play with it and give you best suggestion :)

Comment: The percentage of `margin-right` is related to the parent element which is `ul` and not the `div`, plus using float for this is as you see a pain, you should use `display:inline-block` to make things much easier.

Comment: Not related, Do you realize that `margin-top: 18.18%;` is with respect to width but not height?

Comment: Here is the entire code (It's a subset of the whole page, but is enough for this example) http://jsfiddle.net/M5X6c/2/

Comment: @AliBassam I suspected something like that too, but wasn't too sure. Where should I be using display:inline-block? in ul.nav?

Comment: Just a question, which developer toolbar are you using? It looks so nifty!

Comment: @MR_Green Why is margin-top in relation to width?

Comment: @gersande refer this [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin-top).

Comment: @Mr_Green Somehow that's really counter intuitive. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured it out thanks to @AliBassam 's comment

As he said, the percentage of margin-right is related to the parent element `ul` instead of `div`. The width of the `ul` block is related to how much margin the `li` element has, but if that margin is a percentage of the `ul` width then both elements are depending on each other and it just makes no sense.

To fix that, you need to set a width to ul.nav:

```
ul.nav {
  width: 83%;
  margin-top: 18.18%;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}
```

That is 83% of 600px that is in the `div` containing the `ul.nav` which translates to around 500px

Comment: If this is your answer, you can do ahead and check it off.

Comment: @nouveau Can't accept my own answer until the question is 2 days old

Comment: AH HA - I hadn't run across that.

Comment: on a side note, `margin-top` in percentages is not a good idea. Instead give `positioning` in percentages. Because it maybe looking good on your pc but I am sure it will not look good on wide resolution pc's.

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't know what the height is... so it doesn't know what 18.8% is. You have to declare the html and body 100% height first. and all things within... it's tricky. like @Mr_Green says... it's basing on width because it's insane!!!  also... 18.8 os a whack number. (same with the ul... 6.3498% of what... ? )

Comment: 18.8 is for the margin-top. That's not what I'm having problems with. Ignore that. It's the change between 40px to 6% (or any value really) for margin-right that I am asking ahout

Comment: you don't need to put ul.nav... you can just put .nav by the way. that is unnecessarily specific.

Comment: I beg to differ. Being specific in your CSS selectors is never a bad thing

Comment: I can't explain it... but it has to cross reference more things that way. Is the width of the ul defined?

Comment: It wasn't, but it needed to be! I've fixed that and posted it as an answer.

Comment: What a mess. Good Luck! I'm glad you got an answer!